# Using same 'WHERE' clause for JOIN and UNION and subqueries

Tags: sql, db2

Is it possible to use the WHERE clause just once (if it's the same) for your JOINs and UNIONs. Let say I have a query like this:

```
Select 'some columns and formulas', T2.'some more columns' FROM table table1

LEFT Join 
(Select 'some columns and formulas' FROM select 
('some columns and  formulas' from table2 where DATE_COLUMN > '2018-01-01')) as T2 ON
(table1.ID = T2.ID)

where DATE_COLUMN > '2018-01-01'

Union 

select 'some columns and formulas' from table3 where DATE_COLUMN > '2018-01-01'
```

I am because the join is in a sub query I am not able to join on DATE_COLUMN... and in effect I am forced to use the same where clause 3 times. I am trying to prepare an .ODC file for the users to run themselves and I'd like them to modify the date criteria only once and not 3 times. What are your thoughts. Is somehting like this even possible? Oh, I am using DB2 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the `union` in a subquery, such as this:

```
Select * 
from ((select 'some columns and formulas', T2.'some more columns'
        from table1 left Join 
      ) union 
      (select 'some columns and formulas'
       from table3
      )
     ) tt    
where DATE_COLUMN > '2018-01-01';
```

If `date_column` is not one of the columns being selected, then you will need to include it in the subqueries.

If the `date_column` affects the duplicate elimination from the `union`, then you can do:

```
Select distinct . . . 
from ((select 'some columns and formulas', T2.'some more columns', date_column
        from table1 left Join 
      ) union all
      (select 'some columns and formulas', date_column
       from table3
      )
     ) tt    
where DATE_COLUMN > '2018-01-01';
```

However, I recommend that you use `union all` -- unless you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.